# Как сделать пятиугольный блок!

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image]

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой блок?!

Comment: Ширина блока у Вас фиксированная?

Comment: похожий вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699977/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-bootstrap/700235#700235

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.clip-polygon {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%);
}
```

```html
<img class="clip-polygon" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-640-480-1.jpg">
```

Comment: Дай бог здоровьечка=)))

Comment: там чел внизу одновременно со мной запостил. Упомяну так же, что вот тут редактор есть http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ , а ещё у меня свойство clip-path не работало в (очень) старой мобилке

Answer (score 3):

например с помощью `clip-path`:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.box {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/pics/miami.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.img-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
}

.img-box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #fff;
  border-right: 300px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.img-box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #fff;
  border-left: 300px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
  <img src="http://demo.interface.club/limitless/layout_2/LTR/default/assets/images/demo/flat/15.png" alt="Image">
</div>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/verstala/tokoc6do/