# Как можно сделать такой вот треугольник?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: После треугольника идет интерактивная карта]

Синяя секция заканчивается треугольником. Далее идет карта. Карта интерактивная. 
При ресайзе треугольник всегда должен быть на ширину всего окна браузера.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+css

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Стилизация блоков, как создать шестиугольный блок?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699977/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.clip-polygon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
  background-color: #5252527d;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.map {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #ffaeae;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="clip-polygon">
    <p>Выезжем к Вашему авто
      <br/>в любую точку Москвы</p>
  </div>
  <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Также можно использовать для этих целей `svg`, будет работать и в IE

```css
.clip-polygon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  background-color: #5252527d;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
}

polygon {
  fill: #000000bf
}

;
.map {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #ffaeae;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1280 70" enable-background="new 0 0 1280 70" xml:space="preserve">
   <polygon points="0,0 1280,0 1280,20 640,70 0,20">
   </polygon>
   <text text-anchor="middle" x="640" y="40" fill="white">
     Подгоним машину туда куда надо
    </text>
  </svg>
  <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не работает в IE и Edge. Нужно чтобы треугольник под надписью с фоном по высоте был всегда 90 px.

Comment: Подошел clip-path. Высоту треугольника высчитал через JS. Пришлось проигнорировать IE и Edge.

Answer (score 1):

```css
:root {
  --color: #000;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin:30px auto;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-top: 40px solid var(--color);
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item p {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  border-left: 40vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 40vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid var(--color);
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.header-title {
  color: #fbfbfb;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <p class="header-title">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, et!
  </p>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae ea natus sunt, nam tenetur nesciunt, est reprehenderit dolore, alias, eius sit quod! Est totam blanditiis voluptatem deleniti quas voluptatum culpa aperiam quidem sunt ducimus quae,
      possimus quos eligendi nihil odio dolorem! Ipsum blanditiis quaerat voluptate officia dolores at pariatur minima doloribus quasi, culpa, id. Eius dignissimos praesentium quae id debitis excepturi dolorum repellat cupiditate necessitatibus porro
      voluptate, dicta mollitia ea maxime fugiat in harum dolores doloremque itaque eveniet commodi! Voluptatum sed sapiente et, numquam dolor suscipit, temporibus eius, corporis ratione itaque quisquam atque iure quo fugit! Minima, exercitationem, facilis!
      Consequuntur.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать повёрнутый ромб:

```css
:root {
  --titleHeight:90px;
  --titleSquareSize: calc(var(--titleHeight)*1.414);
  --titleRatio: 12;
}

body {
  background: wheat;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: var(--titleHeight);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 20px; padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: var(--titleSquareSize);
  height: var(--titleSquareSize);
  margin: calc(var(--titleSquareSize)/-2);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleX(var(--titleRatio)) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  Как можно сделать <br>такой вот треугольник?
</div>
```

Вариант адаптивный, кроссбраузерный (может только префиксы для совсем бородатых добавить надо + статично вставить значения переменных).

Comment: Не сразу заметил, что у вас фон и это только кусок предыдущего блока. Тут либо забить на ie/edge (это нормальная практика) и сделать с `clip-path`, либо как-то дизайн так подогнать, чтобы кусок с треугольником был сплошным цветом.